# rsync synchronize -delete

Tags: backup, rsync

I usually backup **from** *server1* files **to** a *server2* machine by doing the following in *server1*

```
rsync --progress -avhe ssh www/ user@10.10.10.10:/home/user/www
```

What I'm looking for is to completely synchronize files on *server2* based on what is currently on *server1*. I know that there are several extra files on *server2* that probably I want to remove.

How could I perform this using rsync?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

rsync has a `--delete` flag: http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/rsync/